# how to check NULL value in SQL with PHP if datatype of fields is integer

Tags: php, sql-server

My data table have `isRej` field has two values `1` and `NULL`. Some records has `isRej = 1` and some has `isRej= NULL`.
Records which are `isRej = 1` are display properly but those have `isRej` is `NULL` are not displaying. 
This work fine
`$sql = WHERE Name = '$name' and isRej =1 ;`
but 
`$sql = WHERE Name = '$name' and isRej !=1 ;` not working.

Comment: null cannot be tested for with `=`, `<>`, etc.. By definition null is not equal to ANYTHING, including itself. that's why there's `is [not] null`

Comment: and isRej is not NULL
this also not working and record not fetching even

Comment: if nulls aren't allowed in the field, why even bother testing for them?

Comment: Actually i haveto display two lists. one is isRej = 1 and other is isrej has NULL value. My database is in SQL server with PHP code.

Comment: are you try with isRej=''

Comment: Yes but  isRej='' not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IS NULL` SQL operation. For example;

```
$tblName = "yourtablename";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tblName WHERE Name = '".$name."' and (isRej != 1 OR isRej IS NULL)";
```